# Parámetros cadena opcionales en WebApi

Tags: string, url, parametros, webapi

tengo hecha una webapi con una función que recibe una serie de parámetros y funciona perfectamente pero tengo uno de tipo cadena cuyo valor debe ser opcional y por defecto es la cadena vacía.

El problema es que al ser un valor por defecto con la cadena vacía, al llamar a la url de la webapi, da una excepción en el request porque me obliga a poner algo en ese campo, pese a que está declarado como opcional. ¿Cómo puedo llamarlo?

La función de la webapi es algo así:

`public ActionResult Get(string nombre, string valor, DateTime fecha, string serie = "", bool contabilizar = true, bool crearcartera = true, bool usar_cola = false)`

A partir de serie es opcional, pero el parámetro serie me da error como que es obligatorio.

He probado a hacer el request con una url sin poner el parámetro en la url, poniendo &serie=, pero nada. He probado con el postman para ver cómo lo hace y también da error lo ponga como lo ponga. Igual puedo declarar el parámetro de alguna manera diferente para que sea opcional pero no se me ocurre cómo.

Gracias,

Marcos.